# React-native SvgUri how to send path for image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi i am making a small component for input and when i try to send data for icon prop i get error this error.

error: components\commonComponents\IconInput.js: components\commonComponents\IconInput.js:Invalid call at line 20: require("" + this.props.iconName)

This is my component.

```
return (
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 40, borderRadius: 8, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#D6D6D6', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
    <SvgUri width="16" height="16" style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 5}} source={require(`${this.props.iconName}`)} />    
    <TextInput
      style={{fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Archivo', color: '#424242'}}
      value={this.props.value}
      multiline={false}
      placeholder={this.props.mainProps.language.email}
      placeholderTextColor="#999"
      editable={false}
    />
</View>
)
```

And this is my other component where i am calling this input component and send props.

```
          <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 24, paddingVertical: 24}}>
            <Text>input</Text>
            <Input value={this.state.order.customerId?.email } mainProps={this.props.mainProps} iconName={'../../resources/Envelope.png'}/>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do something like this:

```
  <SvgUri width="16" height="16" style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 5}} source={require(`${this.props.iconName}`)} />
```

You should put the require() one into a variable and then you can set it into the JSX one.

I believe you cannot use require with dynamic string, so I strongly suggest you that put the require images into a lookup and use it with it.

Here is the example:

```
    const images = {
        image1: require('./images/image1.png'),
        image2: require('./images/image2.png'),
        image3: require('./images/image3.png'),
        image4: require('./images/image4.png'),
        image5: require('./images/image5.png')
    }
        
    // Usage
    images[this.props.iconName]
```

This is just an example, you should struct this for own case.